# Numerical integration Loop Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to write a program that solves the definite integral below in a loop which considers a different value of the constant c per iteration.

I would then like each solution to the integral to be outputted into a new array.

How do I best write this program in python?

[image]

*with limits between 0 and 1.*

`from scipy import integrate`

`integrate.quad`

Is acceptable here. My major struggle is structuring the program.

Here is an old attempt (that failed)

```
# import c
fn = 'cooltemp.dat'
c = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[1])

I=[]
for n in range(len(c)):

    # equation
    eqn = 2*x*c[n]

    # integrate 
    result,error = integrate.quad(lambda x: eqn,0,1)

    I.append(result)

I = array(I)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: What method of numerical integration do you wish to use? Trapezoidal rule? Simpson's rule? Gaussian quadrature? Monte Carlo integration? Or do you just want the built-in `scipy.integrate.quadrature` function? Please specify some of these details and show your current progress and we will be happy to help.

Comment: `integrate.quad` is acceptable here. It's more structuring the program to iterate through the constants that I struggle with.

Comment: If c is a constant, why not use the standard solution c*x^2?

Comment: @RolandSmith, here c stands for a constant of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close.

```
fn = 'cooltemp.dat'
c_values = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[1])

I=[]
for c in c_values: #can iterate over numpy arrays directly.  No need for `range(len(...))`

    # equation
    #eqn = 2*x*c[n] #This doesn't work, x not defined yet.

    # integrate 
    result,error = integrate.quad(lambda x: 2*c*x, 0, 1)

    I.append(result)

I = array(I)
```

I think you're a little confused about how `lambda` works.

```
my_func = lambda x: 2*x
```

is the same thing as:

```
def my_func(x):
    return 2*x
```

If you still don't like lambda, you can do this:

```
f(x,c):
   return 2*x*c

#...snip...
integral, error = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(c,) )
```

Comment: @ElizabethPor -- I'm just glad to be helpful.  Good luck with your integrations.

Answer (score 5):

For instance to compute the given integral for c in [0, 9] :

```
[scipy.integrate.quadrature(lambda x: 2 * c * x, 0, 1)[0] for c in xrange(10)]
```

This is using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [lambda functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms).

Alternatively, you could define the function which returns the integral from a given c as a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (thanks to [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)). This is perhaps more in the spirit of numpy.

```
>>> func = lambda c: scipy.integrate.quadrature(lambda x: 2 * c * x, 0, 1)[0]
>>> ndfunc = np.vectorize(func)
>>> ndfunc(np.arange(10))
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

Comment: This looks good. Rather than xrange(10) how do I get it to compute the integral for c equalling values from an array?

Comment: See alternative solution given above

Answer (score 0):

```
constants = [1,2,3]

integrals = []                                  #alternatively {}

from scipy import integrate

def f(x,c):
    2*x*c

for c in constants:
    integral, error = integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x,c),0.,1.)
    integrals.append(integral)                 #alternatively integrals[integral]
```

This will output a list of just like Nicolas answer, for whatever list of constants.